# Why Method Overriding is runtime bound

Tags: c#, methods, time, overriding, bind

`Overriding` is a principle that allows you to change the functionality of a method in a child class.

For Ex.

```
//Overriding
public class test
{
        public virtual getStuff(int id)
        {
            //Get stuff default location
        }
}

public class test2 : test
{
        public override getStuff(int id)
        {
            //base.getStuff(id);
            //or - Get stuff new location
        }
}
```

When we `Inherit` test class in test2 at that time compiler knows that there is a virtual method in parent class. 
Then why Method overring is runtime bound and not compile time bound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is run-time binding (if that is even the right phrasing - I'm not convinced) because even with a `test2` variable you could actually have:

```
test2 obj = new test3(); // imagine test3 inherits from test2
obj.getStuff(id);
```

here the *variable* is a `test2`, but the object is a `test3`. You could argue that maybe if it was `sealed` etc, but actually even non-virtual instance (non-static) methods go through the callvirt process. It works well, and is very fast. Additionally, the callvirt opcode has the necessary null-check, which means your code doesn't (under the bonnet) have to constantly check for nulls (which would be necessary if it was static-call)

The only exception here is `struct`s which override an `object` method; the following is a **static** call:

```
int i = 1;
string s = i.ToString();
```

Comment: Do structs really override the methods of object? Given that it's a static call. I call shenanigans!

Comment: @John to all intents and purposes they do - at least, in their boxed form - as I could have written: `object o = 1; string s = o.ToString();` - that would still use the correct `ToString()` override. This scenario would compile as a regular callvirt.

Comment: C# always checks for nulls unless you use unsafe or something crazy, if your code doesn't check for nulls you aren't going to get seg fault in any case(I think even in unsafe context the runtime will catch the seg fault and will try to find out what happened where).

Comment: @Dani - no, C# doesn't check for nulls **at all**. The `callvirt` opcode is responsible for this (check the IL). That is indeed one of the points I make above.

Comment: @Marc I've just spent almost an hour trying out various situations where structs behave in thier own way and I'm not getting any smarter. It does however make perfect sense but it's definitely an exceptional case.

Comment: FYI in the literature it is usually referred to as late binding, but run time binding would probably be acceptable also

Comment: @KyleM I would interpret "late" binding as `dynamic`, personally

Comment: Perhaps the terminology is different in .NET then, but in Java late binding and dynamic binding are usually referred to as the same thing: also involved in the process by which polymorphism determines what method to invoke. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this snippet.

```
test Create()
{
    return new test2();
}

test a = Create();
a.getStuff(0); // which method is called?
```

The compiler can't know that the return value of the `Create` method is of type test2. It's explicitly hidden.

You should look at this from the compiler's point-of-view. Given that the compiler is looking at the value as if it was of type `test` how could it know to call the `test2.getStuff` method?

Answer (score 1):

```
class BaseClass
{
   public virtual void Test(){
      Console.WriteLine("This is test of base class");
   }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
   public override void Test(){
      Console.WriteLine("This is test of derived class");
   }
}

class DerivedClass1 : BaseClass
{
   public override void Test(){
      Console.WriteLine("This is test of derived class-1");
   }
}
```

now if you use

```
BaseClass b = new DerivedClass();
b.Test(); // This will derived class method
```

Suppose object created by one another method depend on condition but all are derived from `BaseClass`

```
public BaseClass GetObject(int i)
{
    if(i==1) return new DerivedClass();
    if(i==2) return new DerivedClass1();
}

BaseClass b = GetObject(1);
b.Test(); // This will derivedclass method
BaseClass b = GetObject(2);
b.Test(); // This will derivedclass1 method
```

So all thing depend upon value of `i` that can decided at runtime and at runtime depend upon type of reference `b` hold as per that Test method call.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and edit your post according to the format so it appears proper.

Comment: I've done that edit for you; if you click the "edit" link you should see how easy it is to format your post to display code. And as BoltClock says: welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to other answers, anything that a the compiler can't figure out at compile time it makes it to happen at run time by emitting the appropriate code that does the stuff at run time or by using other techniques.